# What happens to IAM roles while moving resources from one subscription to another?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I saw that it's possible in azure to move resources from one subscription in another(forex- DataFactory V2, Kv, SA,Az functions)

What happens to the roles for example- a group with various members had permissions added on to resources before moving it? Do we need to add them again since the resourceID changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to assign the roles again, if you move the resource to another subscription, the roles added in `Access control (IAM)` will not be existing anymore.

Do a test for you:

[image]

[image]